# Swift Autolayout callback function once layout is laid out

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, snapkit

How do I know when the auto-layouts are laid out?

Is there a callback function?

I am using SnapKit, and I would like to setup few things when my views are laid out.

I have something like below,

```
vehicleGroup.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
    make.width.equalTo(self.headerView).offset(-20)
    make.centerX.equalTo(self)
    make.top.bottom.equalTo(self.headerView)
}
```

Once the above view is laid out I want to use the width and height of the view like below,

```
vehicleGroup.contentSize = CGSize(width: vehicleGroup.frame.width, height: vehicleGroup.frame.size.height)
```

Comment: Probably `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no callback but you can override `-layoutSubviews` (where autolayout does its magic) of your `UIView` classes. But there is no guarantee that autolayout has finished its thing, `-layoutSubviews` can be called several times before the view appears on the screen.

If you need that for a `UIViewController`, then you need to override `-viewDidLayoutSubviews` which is very similar to `-layoutSubviews` of `UIView`